# Why I am getting blank value for SourceDir in a managed Custom Action in WIX?

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer, custom-action

Here is the code for the Product.wxs I am using:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="abc" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="def" UpgradeCode="2b75c560-783e-4688-9a02-da09bf986597">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />

    <Binary Id="myCustomActionsDLL" SourceFile="..\SetupConfiguration\bin\debug\SetupConfiguration.CA.dll" />
    <CustomAction Id="SetProperty" Execute="immediate"
                        Property="CA_myCustomAction"
                        Value="InstallDir=[MergeRedirectFolder];SourceDir=[SourceDir]" />
    <CustomAction Id="CA_myCustomAction"
        BinaryKey="myCustomActionsDLL"
        DllEntry="SetABCConfiguration"
        Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"
        Return="check" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="SetProperty" After="InstallInitialize">Not Installed</Custom>
      <Custom Action="CA_myCustomAction" Before="InstallFinalize">Not Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="abc" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ABCGroup" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="def" Name="def">
          <Directory Id="dirFC83E07AC2C77525961486C88A01C277" Name="ABC">
            <Directory Id="MergeRedirectFolder"/>
          </Directory>
          </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult SetABCConfiguration(Session session)
{
    string strSourceFolder = session.CustomActionData["SourceDir"]; // returning blank value
    string strWebGeniePhyPath = session.CustomActionData["InstallDir"]; // returning correct value
}
```

I have deliberately left out the code for component `ABCGroup`, it just contains a heat harvested directory, which is a long list.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SourceDir property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371857%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is set by the [ResolveSource Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  WiX doesn't author the ResolveSource action by default, you have to add it to your sequence using the [ResolveSource Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/resolvesource.html).

Comment: But, I have still not added this ResolveSource element in the below solution and it is working?

Comment: Look at the build MSI in Orca.  It's hard to say without full source, build installer and/or  installer log file.

Comment: There's an implicit ResolveSource at first install, that's how that works. If you have added a ResolveSource to your setup then make sure it doesn't get called all the time because it will want the original install MSI available.

Comment: Thanks, Phil. Any idea where in the SDK that implicit call is documented?

Comment: Chris, I don't think it's documented, some MSI guy said it in a talk or told me. It just struck me as one of those useful things worth filing away.

Comment: Agreed. I've spent countless time reading the SDK trying to assimilate it's trivia and yet there is always some passing tidbit (documented or not) that alludes me.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution myself by just trying things:

Just change the following line:

```
  <Custom Action="SetProperty" After="InstallInitialize">Not Installed</Custom>
```

to this line:

```
  <Custom Action="SetProperty" After="CreateFolders">Not Installed</Custom>
```

and it works.

I don't know why this change works, because the code in question was working when it was in a merge module rather than in the main `Product.wxs` file.