# Not able to expand property SourceDir in Custom Action ExeCommand

Tags: windows, wix

I'm trying to get Directory SourceDir expanded in my custom action.

My current work looks like this...

```
<CustomAction Id="CopyShortcutBack" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" 
          Execute="commit" Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" 
ExeCommand='cmd.exe /k copy "[APPLICATIONFOLDER]MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" &quot;\&quot;[SourceDir] \&quot;&quot; ' 
              />
```

The """ and "\&quot" are attempts to make it work after reading this question in stackoverflow...
[Not able to send Wix SourceDir path with spaces to custom action ExeCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696602/not-able-to-send-wix-sourcedir-path-with-spaces-to-custom-action-execommand)

However, nothing works.  SourceDir doesn't get expanded with or without any combination of quotes around it.  Note that my ExeCommand also includes [APPLICATIONFOLDER], which IS being expanded.

The command that wix runs, which I get via `wmic` in another open cmd.exe is...

```
cmd.exe /k copy "C:\Users\Mikey\AppData\Local\Apps\Mikey\Personal\Shortcut Test\MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" "\" \""
```

Note also that the expansion of [APPLICATIONFOLDER] does have a space in it, so I wouldn't suspect that spaces are the problem inside [SourceDir].

A bit more code out of my .wsx file if it's relevant.  I commented some of my failed attempts...

```
   <Shortcut Id="MikeySourceToExcelShortcut"
            Name="MikeySourceToExcelShortcut"
            Description="For finding the installation directory"
            Target="[APPLICATIONFOLDER]"
            WorkingDirectory="SourceDir"/>


</Component>


<!--
The simple way I think it should be...
          ExeCommand='cmd.exe /k copy "[APPLICATIONFOLDER]MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" "[SourceDir]" ' 



ExeCommand='cmd.exe /k copy "[APPLICATIONFOLDER]MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" "&quot;[SourceDir]&quot;" ' 
gave...
cmd.exe /k copy "C:\Users\Mikey\AppData\Local\Apps\Mikey\Personal\Shortcut Test\MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" """" 


ExeCommand='cmd.exe /k copy "[APPLICATIONFOLDER]MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" "\&quot;[SourceDir]\&quot;" ' 
gave...
cmd.exe /k copy "C:\Users\Mikey\AppData\Local\Apps\Mikey\Personal\Shortcut Test\MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" "\"\"" 

ExeCommand='cmd.exe /k copy "[APPLICATIONFOLDER]MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" &quot;\&quot; [SourceDir]\&quot;&quot; ' 
gave...
cmd.exe /k copy "C:\Users\Mikey\AppData\Local\Apps\Mikey\Personal\Shortcut Test\MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" "\"\"" 


ExeCommand='cmd.exe /k copy "[APPLICATIONFOLDER]MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" &quot;\&quot;[SourceDir] \&quot;&quot; ' 
gave...
cmd.exe /k copy "C:\Users\Mikey\AppData\Local\Apps\Mikey\Personal\Shortcut Test\MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" "\" \"" 
-->

<CustomAction Id="CopyShortcutBack" Directory="APPLICATIONFOLDER" 
              Execute="commit" Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" 
ExeCommand='cmd.exe /k copy "[APPLICATIONFOLDER]MikeySourceToExcelShortcut.lnk" &quot;\&quot;[SourceDir] \&quot;&quot; ' 
              />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CopyShortcutBack" After="InstallInitialize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Note that the shorcut itself has WorkingDirectory set to "SourceDir" and this IS ALSO WORKING, i.e. SourceDir is being expanded here.

I will welcome any ideas to get this working.  I don't care if I have to create another property to expand SourceDir and then reference that instead.

BTW I also initially tried just plonking the shortcut directly into SourceDir via the Directory attribute.  It didn't work unfortunately.  It would have been so good if that worked and then I could have bypassed all this custom action stuff.  It's looking suspiciously like Microsoft are disallowing the functionality that I'm trying to achieve (putting a shortcut back into my installation directory).

Answer (score 0):

Well I found an element called ResolveSource...

`<ResolveSource Before="CostFinalize" Suppress="no" />`

I found this link after I found the answer.
[Why I am getting blank value for SourceDir in a managed Custom Action in WIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23773840/why-i-am-getting-blank-value-for-sourcedir-in-a-managed-custom-action-in-wix)

For some reason when I don't know the solution I find all the threads that don't work on google.  Only after I've worked it out do I find other threads with the correct solution.  Very mysterious.  It's happening with other problems too.